# Do concurrent data modifications show up in the middle of paging through a Cassandra ResultSet

Tags: cassandra

Specifically, if using the Reactive Streams interface of the Cassandra Java Driver, if paging through results, can writes kicked off after the query was issued (i.e. inserts or deletes) affect those results?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct -- the result set is not static because the partitions can get updated at any time. Cheers!